# How do i get a string inside of 2 strings?

Tags: python, string

So i have 3 variables.

```
char_in = "("
char_out = ")"
string = "[(0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 50]"
```

How can i get a list of every string inside of char_in and char_out.
like`["0, 0, 255", "250, 250"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayank Porwal's answer works if `char_in` and `char_out` must be `(` and `)`. To work for other characters, they need to be escaped and inserted into the regular expression.

```
>>> string = "[(0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 50]"
>>> char_in = "("
>>> char_out = ")"
>>> re.findall(re.escape(char_in)+'(.*?)'+re.escape(char_out), string)
['0, 0, 255', '250, 250']

>>> string = "[<0, 0, 255>, <250, 250>, 50]"
>>> char_in = '<'
>>> char_out = '>'
>>> re.findall(re.escape(char_in)+'(.*?)'+re.escape(char_out), string)
['0, 0, 255', '250, 250']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module:

```
In [1294]: re.findall('\('+ char_in +'.*?' + char_out+ '\)',string)
Out[1294]: ['0, 0, 255', '250, 250']
```

You can have function like this:

```
In [1309]: def get_in_between(char_in, string, char_out):
      ...:     return re.findall(re.escape(char_in)+'(.*?)'+re.escape(char_out), string)
      ...: 

In [1310]: get_in_between('(','[(0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 50]', ')')
Out[1310]: ['0, 0, 255', '250, 250']
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I need to use char_in and char_out to get the string.

Comment: its just returning a empty list

Comment: I tested and pasted the solution above. It's giving proper result for me. Please paste the code what you are using.

Comment: This version only works if `char_in` and `char_out` are `(` and `)`, because the escaped parentheses are still hard coded into your regular expression.

Comment: `def get_in_between(char_in, string, char_out, num):
    return re.findall('\('+ char_in +'.*?' + char_out+ '\)',string)[num]`